# SQL Server datetime data type does not allow many formats

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, datetime

I have a table in SQL Server 2005 which has a date time field. I want to save the date time value in `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss` format, but I guess SQL Server allows date time in `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.ll` format.

I can save date time value in `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss` format as a varchar, but that defeats my intention of sorting the table on that date time field.

Is there something missing in my approach? Any suggestions?

cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The datetime type does *not* store it in `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.ll`, as you claim.**

Datetime columns are stored as 8-byte *binary* data.  The `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.ll` format is just how it's returned in your query.  To display it in other formats, look at the [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function.

Comment: I thought they are double precision floats, generally 32bit. But it's been a long time since I had a look...

Comment: IEEE 754
floating-point precisions

Half (16-bit)
Single (32-bit)
Double (64-bit)
Quadruple (128-bit) d'oh! You win again :)

Comment: This is also why casting a datetime as float and floor()-ing is the fastest way to cut off the time portion - it's all bit shifting rather than complicated string or date calculations.

Comment: Of course, the downside to the float/floor technique is that it relies on an implementation detail that they are free to change at some point in the future, whereas CONVERT should work forever. But that's all a side issue to this question anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can style the datetime when you select it like so:

```
convert(varchar, [datefield], style)
```

Which allows you to format the date when you get it.  This makes the format when storing it trivial.

Here's a [list](http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/ca-co_1.htm) of all the styles you can use.

Answer (score 0):

The date isn't actually saved in a particular format; it is displayed in either the default format or the format you choose.

Where are you 'seeing' the date? Your application will probably not display the date the same as SQL Server Management Studio.

How a user formats a date so it can be saved is an issue for your application as well (As long as it sends a valid date to the server.).

Answer (score 0):

I must admit I never tried to force the database to keep any particular date/time format. I guess it's not really necessary.

So you have a date/time field and you can sort your data by it? That's about as much you need from a DBMS. Perform the final formatting in the presentation layer of your application.